# Creating a variable for a namespace

Tags: c#

Is it possible to shorten a namespace via a variable?
Example;
Instead of typing "`System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("");`"
i am hoping to be able to make a variable to the location "system.windows"  so i can do `Variable.MessageBox("");`

Comment: Why don't you simply import the Namespace in your App, and then use `MessageBox.Show()` everytime ?! It is shorter than the way you asked for, and also the common way.

Comment: Are you purposely excluding `using System;` at the top of your file? Then you would call it like `MessageBox.Show("Sample message");` which is generally the common way to do this.

Comment: @grovesNL I have a conflict when it comes to things like Messagebox and common controls. I have a refference to forms as well as a normal system refference so some things are dually defined.
this is a wpf app with a forms refference for browser friendlyness

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
using SW = System.Windows;

SW.MessageBox.Show("");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can assign the namesspace variable like

```
using M = System.Windows;

M.MessageBox.Show("");
```

(OR)

Define a method of your own and call it like

```
public void Show(string s)
{
  MessageBox.Show(s);
}
```

Now you can call it like

```
Show("something");
```